# Using Checkboxes in Shiny to Combine Datasets

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app in Shiny using different datasets, and I want users to be able to choose which datasets to look at using checkboxes.

I've managed to figure out how to implement checkboxes and to create a reactive list of which boxes are checked. In addition, I've figured out how to combine specific datasets based on a provided list. However, I'm not sure how to combine these two parts, so to use the checked-boxes list to combine the datasets.

Here are the checkboxes

```
sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "data_id",
      label = "Datasets",
      choices =  c(
        "Data 1",
        "Data 2",
        "Data 3",
        "Data 4",
        "Data 5"
      ),
      inline = TRUE,
      selected = "Data 1"
    ),
    textOutput("chosen_data")

  ),
```

And here is the function to combine datasets

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  make_arr <- reactive({
    arr <- character()
    data1 <- "Data 1" %in% input$data_id
    data2 <- "Data 2" %in% input$data_id
    data3 <- "Data 3" %in% input$data_id
    data4 <- "Data 4" %in% input$data_id
    data5 <- "Data 5" %in% input$data_id

    if (data1) {
      arr <- c(arr, 1)
    }
    if (data2) {
      arr <- c(arr, 2)
    }
    if (data3) {
      arr <- c(arr, 3)
    }
    if (data4) {
      arr <- c(arr, 4)
    }
    if (data5) {
      arr <- c(arr, 5)
    }
    return(arr)
  })

  output$chosen_data <- renderText(make_arr())

  combine_data <- reactive({
    for (value in make_arr()) {
      dataset <- c(dataset, my.list[[value]])
    }
  })

  inspect(dataset)
}
```

If replace make_arr() in the for loop with a hard-coded list and comment out the combine_data line, I'm able to combine datasets. However, if I want to use the list created by the checkboxes, it seems that I need to uncomment the combine_data line, as I get the message

"Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"